# Hitting a limit with Lambda concurrency at just 10 instances

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, multithreading, aws-lambda, parallel-processing

I have produced a simple experiment whereby a parent Lambda function invokes in parallel 10 instances of the child Lambda function. For some reason, one of the child instances does not begin for almost a second after the other 9 instances returned their response. Here is the code for easy reproduction of the problem:

The  child Lambda function:

```py
import json
import time
from stats import Timer, ms_now

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    begin = ms_now()
    timer = Timer()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(
            {'time': timer.stop(),
             'begin': begin,
             'end': ms_now()
            })
    }
```

The parent Lambda function:

```py
import boto3
import json
import concurrent.futures
from stats import Timer, ms_now

client = boto3.session.Session().client('lambda')

def do_lambda():
    mybegin = ms_now()
    timer = Timer()
    response = client.invoke(
        FunctionName = 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:497857710590:function:wherewasit-search',
        InvocationType = 'RequestResponse',
        Payload = json.dumps({}))
    payload = json.loads(json.load(response['Payload'])['body'])
    print(f"Thread began: {mybegin}   Child Lambda began at {payload['begin']} and took {payload['time']}ms   Response after {timer.stop()}ms")

def do_work(n_threads):
    timer = Timer()
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=n_threads + 1) as executor:
        futures = []
        for i in range(n_threads):
            futures.append(executor.submit(do_lambda))
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            pass
    print(f"Joined all: {timer.stop()}ms")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    do_work(10)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Both Lambda functions use the `stats` module for time measurements:

```py
import time

def ms_now():
    return int(time.time_ns() / 1000000)

class Timer():
    def __init__(self, timestamp_function=ms_now):
        self.timestamp_function = timestamp_function
        self.start = self.timestamp_function()
    
    def stop(self):
        return self.timestamp_function() - self.start
```

Here is the output of the parent Lamda function:

```
Thread began: 1699451717589   Child Lambda began at 1699451717602 and took 500ms   Response after 517ms
Thread began: 1699451717585   Child Lambda began at 1699451717602 and took 500ms   Response after 522ms
Thread began: 1699451717587   Child Lambda began at 1699451717604 and took 501ms   Response after 521ms
Thread began: 1699451717591   Child Lambda began at 1699451717606 and took 500ms   Response after 518ms
Thread began: 1699451717593   Child Lambda began at 1699451717608 and took 501ms   Response after 519ms
Thread began: 1699451717596   Child Lambda began at 1699451717610 and took 500ms   Response after 517ms
Thread began: 1699451717594   Child Lambda began at 1699451717609 and took 500ms   Response after 519ms
Thread began: 1699451717598   Child Lambda began at 1699451717615 and took 501ms   Response after 521ms
Thread began: 1699451717600   Child Lambda began at 1699451717614 and took 501ms   Response after 519ms
Thread began: 1699451717602   Child Lambda began at 1699451718837 and took 501ms   Response after 1739ms
```

Notice how the timestamp of the beginning of the child Lambda in the last line is much later than the rest of the instances. It looks like I am hitting some limit, but I could not find anything relevant in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html). What is this limit and how do I work around it?

P.S. The question [at re:Post](https://repost.aws/questions/QUFTAZ8d4tTri6vHi74fSF_w/hitting-a-limit-with-lambda-concurrency-at-just-10-instances)

Comment: IIRC, the number of available threads is limited by the memory of your lambda function. I think someone had a medium article on this

Comment: https://medium.com/@jvroig/multithreading-in-aws-lambda-part-1-performance-scaling-6e2bc3d7796f

Comment: what's the memory you have provisioned for your lambda function?

Comment: does it have anything to do with child lambdas at all? what happens if you replace the child lambda call with `time.sleep(0.5)`?

Comment: @monte This happens even with 10240 MB of RAM for the parent Lambda function.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: I mean replace `client.invoke` with `time.sleep` in the parent lambda

Comment: @Quassnoi Then the whole thing is done in 514 ms.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: what if you instantiate the client within the thread rather than reusing it? I don't do a lot of Python but I remember it not being thread safe

Comment: @Quassnoi The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/best-practices.html#bestpractice1) advises to re-use the clients and says explicitly that all AWS clients are thread-safe.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: I think you're hitting some kind of python-specific "concurrency within a lambda" rather than "Lambda concurrency". Might be boto3, might be the underlying http library, might be the threads yielding on sleep and not yielding on whatever happens within the client.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: In Java (which is what you're linking to) and C#, definitely. In Python, [emphatically not](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html#multithreading-or-multiprocessing-with-resources)

Comment: @Quassnoi I moved the initialization of `client` inside `do_lambda()` and still observed the same phenomenon.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning what happens if you run your parent lambda from your laptop? Or better yet, just a bunch of `aws lambda invoke` in parallel?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning also, just to rule out the obvious, what are your Lambda services quotes set to?

Comment: Is this a new AWS account? That could explain the low concurrency. Per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html): "New AWS accounts have reduced concurrency and memory quotas. AWS raises these quotas automatically based on your usage."

Comment: @jarmod It is not a new account (>1 year) though it has only been used for testing so far, which means that there were peaks of activity rather than sustained flow of requests.

Comment: @Quassnoi Oh!!! I was unaware of this obvious thing. It says "Unreserved account concurrency: 10". I will now apply for quota increase. Thank you!

Comment: @Quassnoi I guess it refers to the quota on test events from the console, which is [not adjustable](https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home/services/lambda/quotas/L-AD930C90)

Answer (score 1):

According to random people on the internet ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/z1e8wh/lambda_default_concurrent_executions_only_10_not/), [2](https://benellis.cloud/my-lambda-concurrency-applied-quota-is-only-10-but-why)), new AWS accounts, by default, only get 10 concurrent Lambda executions in the service quotas.

The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) mention it without specifying a particular number:

> New AWS accounts have reduced concurrency and memory quotas. AWS raises these quotas automatically based on your usage.

Comment: There seems to be a [quota](https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home/services/lambda/quotas/L-AD930C90) that's same for all users and it refers to running from the console.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: both posts are mentioning another quota, called "Concurrent Executions"

Comment: Still no resolution of the issue. My "Concurrent Executions" quota is 50. I still encounter the same issue when invoking the parent Lambda function from my laptop (instead of printing, I return those strings in the response and print locally).

Comment: Oops, that was for Frankfurt. In us-east-1, it is really 10. This is strange, because I was always using Lambda in us-east-1... I have requested increase of quota and will test it again once it is hopefully granted. Strangely, it shows 0% utilization...